# Facebook share and likes button

Tags: facebook, share

If looking at the https://stackoverflow.com/ here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ we can see that its have 28667 Likes and 16859 Shares and I can make an button here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button?locale=da_DK that shows the 28667 Likes, but how can I make a button that shows the 16859 Shares ?

Dont Facebook have a tool for that ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button?locale=da_DK

Comment: Yes know that page, the problem is that it also show 28K and not the 16-17K, pleas check the link http://stackoverflow.com/ in the like-button and the share-button and u will see that both will give the 28K count.
but thx for the link, but it didn't help..